# Generate unique short ids on multiple servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, unique

I was using [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid) package to generate unique room ids, it works fine when using with only one server but i don't think ids will be unique if you use it on more than one server. Is there a way to generate unique ids on multiple servers without duplicates?

Comment: `i don't think ids will be unique if you use it on more than one server` why do you think that?

Comment: Add the `server ip` in front of the `id`?

Comment: Often times, the random Id generated will be based off a seed pertaining to current machine time + something that is unique to the machine it's being run on. You may want to read the documentation of shortid to see how it does that. The chances of id collisions are minuscule I feel.

Comment: @KarlReid Servers are not connected to each other, how could it generate ids without duplicates?

Comment: because it uses a random seed on each server, and most likely that seed will be different. The chance of collision is very low. If it's a problem for you, you could always use a more robust solution like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to generate unique ids on multiple servers without duplicates?

From the documentation you link to:

> If you are running multiple server processes then you should make sure every one has a unique worker id. Should be an integer between 0 and 16. If you do not do this there is very little chance of two servers generating the same id, but it is theoretically possible if both are generated in the exact same second and are generating the same number of ids that second and a half-dozen random numbers are all exactly the same.

Comment: What if i have more than 17 servers?

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have server id's 1,2,3 .
so just add server id to the number generated it ensure unique as you know in one server it will surely be unique.